# Backpack Admin: Image Column Type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm struggling with the Laravel Backpack image column type. The [documentation](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#section-image) gives an example:

```
[
   'name' => 'profile_image', // The db column name
   'label' => "Profile image", // Table column heading
   'type' => 'image',
    // optional width/height if 25px is not ok with you
    // 'height' => '30px',
    // 'width' => '30px',
]
```

But I don't know where I'm supposed to put it. I guessed and put it in `$this->crud->setColumns` and the column was added, but couldn't get it working.

I'm guessing theres supposed to be a mutator in the model, but not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where it describes how to [add a column in the documentation](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud#section-columns)